# Div com hide e iframe dentro, porém link não abre

Tags: javascript, jquery, div, iframe

Ao entrarem no [site](http://testandoscript.tk/), vocês poderão ver que vai ter uma div seguindo o mouse, e o conteúdo dela é um iframe. Ao clicarem nessa div ou na imagem do iframe, eles somem, porém, o objetivo principal é clicar no link de dentro do iframe, porém, ao clicar não entra no link, ou seja, o hide está funcionando, mas o link não funciona. Não sei se me expressei bem, podem ficar a vontade para corrigir minhas palavras.

O script usado para esconder a div está [aqui](http://testandoscript.tk/wp-includes/js/jquery/script.js).

O script do "segue o mouse" que estou usando é o seguinte código:

HTML:

```
<div id="position">
  <iframe style="border:none;  width:680px; height:250px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" src="http://saudeonline.info/anuncio/index.html"> </iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#position {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
if (document.all) {} else document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
document.onmousemove = mouse;

function mouse(e) {
  if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
    xcurs = e.pageX;
    ycurs = e.pageY;
  } else {
    xcurs = event.clientX;
    ycurs = event.clientY;
  }
  document.getElementById('position').style.left = (xcurs - 530) + 'px';
  document.getElementById('position').style.top = (ycurs - 60) + 'px';
}
```

Ao entrarem no [site](http://testandoscript.tk/), vai aparecer o banner logo de cara da ArgoConstrutora e o link da imagem na barra de status, porém ao clicar, nao vai pro site, a div fecha.

Comment: Tem algum problema se o click for feito via js? Por que ai você só acrescente no seu código um trechinho bem simples:

$("#position").on("click",function() {
 window.open("http://www.microsoft.com"); 
});

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema é no código do seu iframe. Se você clica em um link dentro de um iframe o comportamento padrão e abrir  a nova janela dentro do próprio iframe (o que você acabou de esconder). Para solucionar isso você pode tentar colocar um `target="_blank"` no link o que instrui o navegador a abrir o link em uma nova página.
 ficaria assim:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.argoconstrutora.com.br/"><img src="img/anuncie.jpg" width="680" height="250" alt=""></a>
```

Tendo dito isso, esse comportamento de obrigar o usuário a clicar em u anúncio e forçar o aparecimento de uma nova janela é considerado ruim e provavelmente vai servir apenas para afastar visitantes do seu site.

Comment: Imaginei que isso resolveria, mas não gostaria de usar o target="_blank" Será que existe alguma outra forma?